# How to 'return' a value in prolog?

Tags: list, prolog

What I am trying to do is append elements from two lists into another and in the end get the value of the new list out in console.
My lists are : A = [a, b]; B(list of pairs) = [(c, cc), (a, aa), (b, bb)]
I want to add the second element of pair of list B if the first element matches the first element of pair (dictionary principle) And I want all those elements to be added in an empty list which the console would output.
What I have so far is this (X would be the empty list):

```
aa(_, [], _) :-
    true.

aa([H|T], [(A, B)|T2], X) :-
    H == A ->
        append([B], X, X2), aa([H|T], T2, X2);
        aa([H|T], T2, X).
```

In console I'm typing: `read(X), trace,aa([a, b], [(c, cc), (a, aa), (b, bb)], X), write(X).`

But it keeps returning the [] value of X. How can I get the value of X2 as output if I am asking for X?
Here is the trace output:

```
 Call:aa([a, b], [(c,cc), (a,aa), (b,bb)], [])
 Call:a==c
 Fail:a==c
 Redo:aa([a, b], [(c,cc), (a,aa), (b,bb)], [])
 Call:aa([a, b], [(a,aa), (b,bb)], [])
 Call:a==a
 Exit:a==a
 Call:lists:append([aa], [], _2110)
 Exit:lists:append([aa], [], [aa])
 Call:aa([a, b], [(b,bb)], [aa])
 Call:a==b
 Fail:a==b
 Redo:aa([a, b], [(b,bb)], [aa])
 Call:aa([a, b], [], [aa])
 Exit:aa([a, b], [], [aa])
 Exit:aa([a, b], [(b,bb)], [aa])
 Exit:aa([a, b], [(a,aa), (b,bb)], [])
 Exit:aa([a, b], [(c,cc), (a,aa), (b,bb)], [])
 Call:write([])
[]
 Exit:write([])
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to put the `;` at the end of a line, it is very easy to overlook it. I prefer a different format, see below. As for your question, you have the arguments to `append/3` in the wrong order. `X2` is the intermediate result from the recursive call, and the result you want to "return" is the combination of this `X2` with the element `B`:

```
aa(_, [], _) :-
    true.

aa([H|T], [(A, B)|T2], X) :-
    (   H == A
    ->  append([B], X2, X), aa([H|T], T2, X2)
    ;   aa([H|T], T2, X) ).
```

The goal `append([B], X2, X)` can be written more clearly as `X = [B|X2]`.

This fixes the immediate problem, but not yet the whole predicate:

```
?- aa([a, b], [(c, cc), (a, aa), (b, bb)], X).
X = [aa|_G22] ;
false.
```

You decompose the first argument into `[H|T]` but don't actually do a recursion over this list, so you never look at `b` and its corresponding element in the list of pairs.

Here's a simple way to do the whole thing:

```
aa([], _Pairs, []).
aa([Key|Keys], Pairs, Values) :-
    (   member((Key, Value), Pairs)
    ->  aa(Keys, Pairs, Values0),
        Values = [Value|Values0]
    ;   aa(Keys, Pairs, Values) ).
```

The key insight here is that once you know a `Key`, you can look for a pair `(Key, Value)` in your list of pairs. `Value` is not bound to a value yet and will be instantiated by `member/2` if it the list contains a pair whose first element is `Key`. This is the power of unification!

This seems to work:

```
?- aa([a, b], [(c, cc), (a, aa), (b, bb)], X).
X = [aa, bb].
```

Finally, you probably don't want to have a `read(X)` before this, since that means that the user must predict the solution!

Comment: This is fascinating! The only thing is, that the code should go through the whole pair list in case element has more than one translation. Could this be achieved with another recursive call of the predicate right before `aa(Keys, Pairs, Values0)` line looping through Pairs?

Comment: There are several possible ways to treat that. If you change the `->` to `*->`, it will enumerate different solutions on backtracking:
    `?- aa([a, b], [(c, cc), (a, aa), (b, bb), (a, aa2)], X).
    X = [aa, bb] ;
    X = [aa2, bb] ;
    false.`
If you want a single solution like `[aa, bb, aa2]`, it's a bit more complex but should be doable using `select/3` instead of `member/2`, doing a recursive call as you mentioned, and calling `append/3` on the results.